# Conversion into XSLD from XML using multiple for-each loop

Tags: xml, xslt

I have following XML values:

```
<Specialties>
    <Specialty>
      <Type>ZZ</Type>
      <Code>DF</Code>
      <Desc>DF</Desc>
    </Specialty>
    <Specialty>
      <Type>ZZ</Type>
    </Specialty>
    <Specialty>
      <Type>ZZ</Type>
      <Code>AF</Code>
      <Desc>AF</Desc>
    </Specialty>
</Specialties>
```

Now i need to create XLST for that so i can convert my output like this:

```
<Specialties>
  <Specialty Type="ZZ" Code="DF" Desc="DF"/>
  <Specialty Type="ZZ"/>
  <Specialty Type="ZZ" Code="AF" Desc="AF"/>
</Specialties>
```

I tried write XSLD like this:

```
<Specialties>
  <xsl:for-each select="/Specialties/*">
    <Specialty>
        <xsl:for-each select="/Specialties/Specialty/*">
            <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
                <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </Specialty>
  </xsl:for-each>
</Specialties>
```

But it gives output:

```
<Specialties>
  <Specialty Type="ZZ" Code="AF" Desc="AF"/>
  <Specialty Type="ZZ" Code="AF" Desc="AF"/>
  <Specialty Type="ZZ" Code="AF" Desc="AF"/>
</Specialties>
```

So my question here is, how to get required output by writing XSLT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line....

```
<xsl:for-each select="/Specialties/Specialty/*">
```

To just this....

```
 <xsl:for-each select="*">
```

This will get all child nodes of the current node. When you start an expression with `/` then this represents the top level document node and so it will get all child nodes of all `Specialty` nodes in the document.